# NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass) Rails3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting an `NoMethodError  (undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass)` in `ArticlesController#create`

The model `Article` is

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :img_data, :tags, :title, :tag_ids, :id
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end
```

, and `ArticlesController#create` is

```
def create
  params[:article][:tag_ids] ||= []
  @article = Article.new params[:article]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save
      format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @article, status: :created, location: @article }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The error message says the error is occurred in the process of `@article.save`. 
What should I do to fix the error?

---

I thought the `name` is came from `Tag`. The model is

```
 class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :id
   has_many :taggings
   has_many :articles, :through => :taggings
 end
```

, and the model, `Tagging` is

```
 class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :article_ids, :tag_ids, :tag_id, :article_id
   belongs_to :article
   belongs_to :tag
 end
```

Comment: It may sounds stupid but several people has this glitch: try to use parentheses for the new method: `Article.new(params[:article])`

Comment: I second the parenthesis method. It has worked for me in the past.

Comment: try debug, see if the object is created after the "new" method